# How to conditionally execute group of tasks on ansible?

Tags: ansible

I want to conditionally execute a set of tasks. Is there any syntax available that would let me execute a group of tasks, where the condition is evaluated once per whole group (like in a `if` statement in programming languages)?

Take a look at the code snippets below. I know the difference is small, but the first code better expresses my intention without polluting the namespace with additional variables (`user_home_result2`).

### Pseudocode of what I want to do:

```
- name: Capturing user's home directory
  shell: "getent passwd {{ user }} | awk -F: '{ print $6 }'"
  register: user_home_result

- set_fact: user_home={{ user_home_result.stdout }}

- when:  user_home != ''  

  - name: Setting up user {{ user }}
    user: >
      generate_ssh_key=yes
      name="{{ user }}"

  - name: Capturing user's home directory
    shell: "getent passwd {{ user }} | awk -F: '{ print $6 }'"
    register: user_home_result

  - set_fact: user_home={{ user_home_result.stdout }}
```

### Walkaround:

```
- name: Capturing user's home directory
  shell: "getent passwd {{ user }} | awk -F: '{ print $6 }'"
  register: user_home_result

- set_fact: user_home={{ user_home_result.stdout }}

- name: Setting up user {{ user }}
  user: >
    generate_ssh_key=yes
    name="{{ user }}"
  when: user_home != ''

- name: Capturing user's home directory
  shell: "getent passwd {{ user }} | awk -F: '{ print $6 }'"
  register: user_home_result2
  when: user_home != ''

- set_fact: user_home={{ user_home_result2.stdout }}
  when: user_home != ''
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can put the tasks in a new yml file and use a conditional include:

```
# subtasks.yml
---
- name: Setting up user {{ user }}
  user: >
    generate_ssh_key=yes
    name="{{ user }}"

- name: Capturing user's home directory
  shell: "getent passwd {{ user }} | awk -F: '{ print $6 }'"
  register: user_home_result

- set_fact: user_home={{ user_home_result.stdout }}
```

And in the playbook:

```
- name: Capturing user's home directory
  shell: "getent passwd {{ user }} | awk -F: '{ print $6 }'"
  register: user_home_result

- set_fact: user_home={{ user_home_result.stdout }}

- include: subtask.yml
  when:  user_home != ''
```

Comment: In ansible 2.0 will be a new syntax (block) that will then do what you want http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_blocks.html

Comment: The updated link for documentation on blocks is https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html

Answer (score 12):

As of version 2.1, ansible has blocks for logical task grouping. Blocks allow you to specify common things for a few tasks only once, including the `when` conditionals. Ex:

```
- block:

    - name: put a file somewhere
      copy: src=asdf dest=asdf

    - name: put another file somewhere
      template: src=asdf.j2 dest=asdf

  when: bool_is_true
```

The above is equivalent to attaching a `when: bool_is_true` to both of the tasks inside the block.

More information at https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html