# Ansible Conditionally Synchronize if Directory Exists

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I would like to use Ansible's `synchronize` module to transfer files to a remote server based on a condition. The condition, is that the *directory* and its contents exist on the source server.

For example:

First play, check if the directory exists on the localhost:

```
hosts: localhost
stat:
  path: some/path/to/dir/
register: st
```

Then, on the second play, use that variable in a `when` statement to conditionally use the `synchronize` module:

```
hosts: remote_hosts
synchronize:
  src: some/path/to/dir/
  dest: some/dest/path
when: st.stat.isdir is defined
```

My problem is that the `st` variable can't be used between plays, so how can I only run the `synchronize` task if the directory exists.

I would put them in the same play, but they're using different hosts as you can see.

My Ansible version is 2.3.1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple options.  You can put the localhost task in your play with `remote_users` and use `delegate_to: localhost`.

```
stat:
  path: some/path/to/dir/
register: st
delegate_to: localhost
```

Or you can keep the localhost play as is and reference localhost's variables using `hostvars` in the remote_hosts play.

```
hosts: remote_hosts
synchronize:
  src: some/path/to/dir/
  dest: some/dest/path
when: hostvars['localhost']['st'].stat.isdir is defined
```

Comment: Thanks for providing multiple approaches; I haven't seen these methods used anywhere. I was about to attempt something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33348077/how-to-conditionally-execute-group-of-tasks-on-ansible but yours is so much more concise